# Authentication for Google Glass for third party application

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I have a sample GDK app ready to be loaded for glass. It would work only if the app is published, and authentication happens from Google to third-party using MyGlass page.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Help with what? You'll need to be more specific in your question. Is there a problem you have encountered, or is something not working as you expected?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a library I wrote for OAuth before Google even had an OAuth solution: https://github.com/victorkp/GlassAuth

And there's an example application for that library here: https://github.com/victorkp/GlassWebNotes

Basically, the GlassAuth library is able to use Google's OAuth for Devices service - the user will see a code displayed on Glass, then he or she can go to a https://google.com/devices on a phone/computer, sign in, and enter that code. At that point, you can use the AuthHttpsTask in the library to make use of the OAuth token.

Comment: Thanks a lot Victor...would work with suggested solution :) thnks again for your reply :)

Comment: No problem, shoot me an email if you have any issues.